# C# XMLSerializer Constructor

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have this code but i don't know what should be in the constructor `Klant()`.
What should come here so the field 'voornaam' comes in the XML?

```
public static void SchrijfKlanten(Klant klant, string pad) {
    using (FileStream file = File.Open(pad, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(klant.GetType()); //THIS LINE
    xml.Serialize(file, klant);
    }
}

public class Klant {
    string voornaam;

    public Klant(){
        //Here
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field should be a public property. Other than that, it should work fine even without any constructor.

```
public class Klant 
{
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Note: in terms of the constructor, this is no different whatsoever. The difference here is primarily the `public` (although making it a property is a good idea too) /cc @Gianni